# Not able to access to element in list<Object*> when iterating c++

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, tostring

I would like to understand why this code doesn't do the job. I want to display column elements contained into Table, but when I run it, it gets stuck and then it displays nothing.

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include "Column.h"
using namespace std;

class Table : public BaseObject{
private:
    string address;
    string name;
    list<Column*> columns;
public:
    Table(string,string);
    Table(string,string,list<Column*>);
    virtual ~Table();
    void save(ostream&) const;
    static Table* read(ifstream&);
    string toString() const;
    list<Column*> getColumns() const;
    string getName() const;
    string getAddress() const;
};

#endif  /* TABLE_H */
```

.cpp file

```
#include"Table.h"

Table::Table(string address, string name){
    this->address = address;
    this->name = name;
}

Table::Table(string address, string name, list<Column*> cols){
    this->address = address;
    this->name = name;
    this->columns = cols;
}

Table::~Table(){
}

string Table::toString() const{
    stringstream ss;

    ss << "\nAddress: " << address
            << "\nName: " << name 
            << "\nColumns: ";
    list<Column*>::const_iterator i;
    for(i=columns.begin(); i != columns.end(); i++){
        ss << (*i)->toString();
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

The toString function just shows Address and Name and then it stops showing nothing until I break it Ctrl + C. Thanks in advance. Any advice overall would be great.

Comment: It would help to see the code where you construct the `Table`.

Comment: can you show us the main function and the code related to Column?

Answer (score 0):

It could be reallocation problem. Each call to operator<< forces stringstream to call realloc() which calls system for more memory (continuous region) and copy data from current location. While number of columns grows as lineary (N columns), stringstream storage grows exponentially (it copys content of all N-1 columns each time).
Most programs becomes slow (or very slow) in similar situation.
Try the following:
1. change ss << (*i)->toString(); to cerr << (*i)->toString(); to see what happens and how many columns do you actually have.
2. If you find above working correct and fast (assumed you did not fined other root cause in the code), try change toString interface and implementation to avoid string and stringstream. For exampe, Table could define own iterator. With Table::iterator you migth not need toString(), it depends on how do the code uses Table:: toString